# How to return context type on Save Record?

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

I'm probably not seeing the obvious here, but here it goes.

I have a SuiteScript 2.0 client script and I'm trying to perform an action on Save Record, only if the record is being edited. I'm able to return the context.mode on Page Init, but I'm getting undefined.

I've tried context.mode and context.type; both return undefined

```
function pageInit(context) {
    alert(context.mode); // returns "edit"
}

function saveRecord(context) {
    alert(context.mode); // returns "undefined"
    // alert(context.type); // returns "undefined"
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The only information you get via `scriptContext` on a `saveRecord` event is a reference to the `currentRecord`. See the Help page for `saveRecord` for details.

To determine whether a record is being created or edited, you just need to check if it already has an internal ID. If `scriptContext.currentRecord.id` is populated, then the record is being edited; otherwise, it's being created.